# Creating constructors for a temperature converter

Tags: java, class, constructor

Write a `Temperature` class that represents temperatures in degrees in both Celsius and Fahrenheit, using a floating-point number for the temperature and character for the scale: either ‘C‘ for Celsius or ‘F‘ for Fahrenheit.  The class should have

Four constructors:

- one for the number of degrees,
- one for the scale,
- one for both the degrees and the scale, and
- a default constructor.

For each of these constructors, assume zero degrees if no value is specified and Celsius if no scale is given."

Hey there I am an amateur java programmer... I have been asked to do the above statement and I am not all that familiar with constructors but I'm open to any knowledge :) obviously I'm not asking for someone to give me an answer to my question but maybe someone can give me some advice on how I get started... here's what I have done so far:

```
public class TemperatureApparatus {

    public class temperature{
        private float c;
        private float F;

        public temperature(){

        }
        public temperature(){

        }
        public temperature(){

        }
        public temperature(){

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/class_constructor.html) first and then try to reorganize your code,

Comment: Congratulations for being the only person that I see in this forum that asks for orientation and not for the answer to his homework (which is different than asking for an answer for a problem that is not homework).
You have my respect.

Comment: haha yeah thanks kinda no point to asking a question if I'm just gonna be spoon fed code you know... no learning happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
public class Temperature {
   private float temp;
   char scale;

   //first constructor
   /*
   *Notice how in this first constructor, I put scale
   *as 'C' since there was no char value being passed
   *as a parameter (no char scale inside the brackets)
   *Now i did get a float temp passed a a parameter so 
   *I set whatever that temp is to the temp of this class
   *also known as this.temp (this refers to THIS class
   */
   public Temperature(float temp) {
      this.temp = temp;
      scale = 'C';
      //other way
      //this(temp, 'C');  
   }

   //second constructor
   /*
   *Now this constructor is the exact same case at the 
   *first one, except this one has the char scale passed.
   *Since no temp is passed, I set it to 0 as no value is specified 
   */
   public Temperature(char scale) {
      this.scale = scale;
      temp = 0;
      //other way
      //this(0, scale); 
   }

   //third constructor
   /*
   *This third one is having both temp and scale being specified
   *which means you don't need to put any initial value (0 and Celcius)
   *Just set these objects to whatever is being passed by through the 
   *parameters
   */
   public Temperature(float temp, char scale) {
      this.temp = temp;
      this.scale = scale;
   }

   //fourth constructor
   /*
   *This last one has no parameters through so
   *you can just set both the scale and temp to 
   *0 and 'C' respectively.
   */
   public Temperature() {
      temp = 0;
      scale = 'C';
      //other way
      //this(0, 'C'); 
   }
}
```

Comment: I might have syntax errors I did this all on stackoverflow so im not 100% sure there aren't any ERRORS

Comment: listen to that other guy as well...Temperature should be one class and then Main as another

Comment: The default constructor and each of the one-parameter constructors should just invoke the 2-argument constructor with the proper values. For example, the default constructor would contain only this line: `this(0., 'C');`

Comment: you can do it like that but i think he is just starting...i was taught that when i learned oop principals, not when i learned what constructors were

Comment: i have commented them out but if you go into the constructors, they will say "Other way" and the line is right under...you either do it the way that is not commented out, or the way that is...not both

Answer (score 1):

> Four constructors: one for the number of degrees, one for the scale,
>   one for both the degrees and the scale, and a default constructor.

These are your constructor *arguments*. Arguments are passed into constructors and methods via *parameters* which are listed within the parentheses of the method.

You've got the format of a constructor correct. It's essentially a method that has the same name of the class and no return type. Now you need to add arguments.

The default constructor has no arguments:

```
public Temperature() { //Class names should be capitalized!
    //Default constructors often do nothing, but you can set default values here if you want
}
```

Here's a signature for a constructor taking the degrees only:

```
public Temperature(float degrees) {
     //Assign the "degrees" argument to an instance variable here
     //You might consider assigning a value to a "scale" variable by default as well
}
```

This assignment probably wants you to fill in that constructor's body, so assign the given value to a `float` in the class. Now make constructors for the other desired arguments. Since the assignment wants 'F' or 'C' for the scale, you can safely use `char` as the argument for that data.

Once you've completed the assignment, you might consider challenging yourself with this: Given that a user could now have a `Temperature` object with a `float` degree and a `char` scale, how might you implement a `getTemperature()` method?

Oh, and there's no reason for you to nest classes like you are. Put `Temperature` in a separate class from your class that runs `main` if you need to make a runnable answer.

Comment: makes better sense now... i gotta keep trying at it. thanks!